# jQuery: Fluid isotope only working after resize

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope, fluid-layout

I'm having some trouble with a fluid isotope grid I'm setting up, a simple 4 column grid, each `.grid-block` being 24% width, leaving a 1% allowance.
The problem is though, when the page loads it's displaying as a 3 column grid until the browser window is resized and it snaps into 4 columns.
Here's a jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BVzTV/4/ 
jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $container = $('#main-grid');

$container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.grid-block',
    animationEngine: 'best-available',
    resizable: false,
    masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() / 4 }
    });

    $(window).smartresize(function(){
  $container.isotope({
    // update columnWidth to a percentage of container width
    masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() / 4 }
  });
    });
});
```

I can't figure out why this is happening / how to fix it, its simple really I'm just trying to achieve a simple 4 column grid when the page loads, and when it's resized. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: +1 - Very nice question. Reproducible with a demo, and a clear issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/9x9eG/)***

The optimized grid is inside of the settings for smartresize. You could just make a single call to the resize function when the page loads like this:

```
$(window).smartresize();//I know it seems kind of simple, but it works
```