# Photo Alignment when page loads should be grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a page with picture that need to be displayed in a grid starting with 3 columns. But every time the page loads, the pictures all load as one column going straight down the left side of the page.

It is only once you stretch the browser that the photo realign.

I want it already in a grid of 3 columns as soon as page loads.

any ideas?

```js
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    
    

    <script type="{{site.baseurl}}/js/scrollspy.js"></script>
    <script src="swipebox/lib/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
    <script src="swipebox/lib/ios-orientationchange-fix.js"></script>
    <script src="swipebox/lib/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>

    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
                 //When the DOM document is loaded in the browser

            $(document).ready(function () {
        
    
    
    
      <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#menu-close").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
  $("#menu-toggle").show("active");
  $("#menu-close").hide("active"); 
  

    });

    // Opens the sidebar menu
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
  $("#menu-close").show("active"); 
  $("#menu-toggle").hide("active"); 
  
  
  
    });


     // Closes the sidebar menu
    $("#menu-close2").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#sidebar-wrapper2").toggleClass("active")//slideUp(50);
    });

    // Opens the sidebar menu
    $("#menu-toggle2").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#sidebar-wrapper2").toggleClass("active")//slideDown(50);
    });

    /* Basic Gallery */
          
          
   
      
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Scrolls to the selected menu item on the page
    $(function() {
        $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

                var target = $(this.hash);
                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
                if (target.length) {
                    $('html,body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top
                    }, 1000);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

 

                    <script src="bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

      <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/classie.js"></script>
    <script src="js/cbpAnimatedHeader.js"></script>

    <!-- Contact Form JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
    <script src="js/contact_me.js"></script>
    

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/agency.js"></script>

      
<script src="lib/ios-orientationchange-fix.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.swipebox.js"></script>

<!--  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/SmoothScroll.js"></script>
 -->    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.isotope.js"></script>
 
  <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".swipebox").swipebox();
});
</script>




 <!-- 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {

            /* Basic Gallery */
            $( '.swipebox' ).swipebox();
            
            /* Video */
            $( '.swipebox-video' ).swipebox();

            /* Dynamic Gallery */
            $( '#gallery' ).click( function( e ) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.swipebox( [
                    { href : 'http://swipebox.csag.co/mages/image-1.jpg', title : 'My Caption' },
                    { href : 'http://swipebox.csag.co/images/image-2.jpg', title : 'My Second Caption' }
                ] );
            } );

      });
    </script>
     -->
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script> -->
<script src="js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<!-- <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
 --><script src='http://npmcdn.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.js'></script>

<script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

```css
  <link href="font-awesome/fonts/plugin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/plugin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo/bagpakk.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/swipebox.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylish-portfolio.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="swipebox/src/css/swipebox.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="swipebox/src/css/swipebox.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="swipebox/demo/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="swipebox/demo/bagpakk.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="swipebox/demo/style.css">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/owl.carousel.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/owl.theme.css"media="screen">
    

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

```html
    <section id="portfolio" class="portfolio" style="display: none;" >
             <div class="container">
   
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 text-center">
                    <h2><font style="text-transform: uppercase;"face="Helvetica" >Portfolio</font></h2>
                    <hr class="large">
                </div>
                </div>
                 
<div class="button-group filters-button-group">
  <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="*">show all</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=".ling">Lingeria</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=".men">Men</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=".women">Women</button>
</div>
                 
<div class="grid">
  <div class="element-item men " data-category="men">
  
  <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="img/1.jpg" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
  
  </div>
  
  <div class="element-item ling" data-category="ling">
   <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="img/2.jpg" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
  
  </div>
  
   <div class="element-item men" data-category="men">
   <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="img/3.jpg" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
  
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="element-item women" data-category="women">
   <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="img/4.jpg" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
  
  </div>
  
  <div class="element-item ling " data-category="ling">
   <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="img/5.jpg" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
  
  </div>
 </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to end of `Document.ready()` :

```
$( window ).resize()
```

I think that should work, it calls the resize event on the browser which should trigger the change.

Ps: I'd suggest getting rid of all the different versions of Jquery you have loaded on your page.

Comment: where am I putting it? I put it like this but it still doesnt work: 


            $(document).ready(function () { 
   
   $(window).resize();

Comment: Maybe the following link could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17264269/jquery-fluid-isotope-only-working-after-resize